# A three-times-betrayed person will have been betrayed four times [complete]

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does *a three-times-betrayed person will have been betrayed four times* make sense?

I mean a person has been betrayed three times and will have been betrayed four times.

I think *a three-times-betrayed person will have been betrayed four times* means *a person who will have been betrayed three times at a specific time will have been betrayed four times at the same time* and is a bit awkward.

I think I should say: *a person betrayed three times “before” will  have been betrayed four times.*

Comment: Are you trying to use it as a general saying (ie. "someone who falls for something multiple times will probably fall for it again"), or to describe a literal situation of a person being betrayed three times and about to be betrayed the fourth time? The phrasing makes it sound like a proverb, but the question seems to be asking for the literal sense.

Comment: Yes literal sense~

Comment: It's understandable and fairly grammatical, although most English speakers probably wouldn't use *three-times-betrayed* as a single compound adjective. I'd rephrase it as "A person who was betrayed three times will be betrayed again".

Comment: (it still sounds like a proverb to me, but I'm assuming it makes sense in context)

Comment: I will rewrite the question please wait :)

Comment: Hi again! Grammatically, he correct version of the sentence is, I think, *A three-times-betrayed person will be betrayed four times*. *three-times-betrayed* is a past participal adjective, which generally indicates that something happened to the described object in the past, ie. the person has been betrayed three times before, and *will be* betrayed for the fourth time in the future.

Comment: (your rewrite, for that matter, is no longer grammatical - *will been* is invalid. *will be* is right if you expect them to be betrayed in the future. *Will have been* might work in some contexts, but I can't think of any applicable ones at the moment - *will be* is most likely intended.

Comment: OMG I mean will have been I’m so stupid :(

Comment: By the way, a past participle must be used for the past?

Comment: It is a little poetic, but we already have a specific word for "three-times (something)": [**thrice**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thrice)

Comment: @stangdon Sorry but a past participle must be used only for the past?

Comment: @하아아아앙  It is hard to answer that question without a specific example.

Comment: @stangdon no no I mean in any case even in one of all cases that is not used for the past

Answer (score 1):

If you have been betrayed three times, that means you have placed your trust three times in a person who is untrustworthy (who may or may not be the same person).

Thus you have a history of not learning whom you can trust and whom you cannot trust.

Hence you are likely to do the same thing a fourth time: trust somebody untrustworthy, and in turn be betrayed again.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was not clearly said, so I rewrote it.